# Find debugging printf to remove it

Tags: c++, debugging, printf, cout

I ran into some problem that I want to solve efficiently and maybe some of you will learn from this too.
I made a mistake, because I debbuged my application using printf( or in my case probably std::cout) debbuging.
It went well and I removed my bug and got to other problems.
Now I am at a stage where I want my debugging output to vanish but I can not find it anymore.
Searching the text did not bring it up and is hopeless because of many non-debug prints.
Further I did not print more than a variables value so I don't know it's name nor can I search for this specific value as it is not in the source code.

I remember of some neat linux command that logs all syscalls in the application it wraps.
Is it possible to use this tool to find the lines where the debugging print takes place?
(I would use this because 90% of my output is this debugging print so i think i should find it quickly)

Of course if you know about a better way to solve this you are welcome to post your solution.

Thanks

**EDIT**
To not comment on each one who advices me to use version control: I already use SVN.
Unfortunately I do not know when I entered the debugging message.
Worst case could be that my initial commit already contains it.

The grep guys: That is not much better than the text search as it will give me each
line containing a print/std::cout and that without context, so I cant even decide if
it is a debugging line between all these others.

To all of you who tell me/think I am stupid doing these things: Well that one I noticed just as I typed in this post ;)

But let me state that I all this comes down to my laziness in former times so let this be an example for all of you how laziness leads to even more work later on.
I just needed one single debug print there so I decided to code it in the dirty way. If it had been more I probably would have used a better one.

**Solved**

Finally I found it, with some luck.
It was a std::cout that had hidden somewhere deeper in code(one of the base classes that had only few includes that all were system-libraries).
I tried the grep method with one -F1 to see any comments and had luck with the line in question being on the screen when grep was through.

Comment: Avoid the problem in the future by using version control?

Comment: Maybe you can look back through the logs on your version control system to find out where the debugging happened and do a diff around that time ?

Comment: `grep "std::cout" * -r | grep text`

Comment: Are you sure that your `make clean` erases all object files and rebuilds them, and that you are not running an old executable?

Comment: You can use `strace(1)` to track system calls, but formatted I/O operations do not necessarily result in system calls because of the buffering.  However, it does not include line number or file name information for the calls.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok that was the one I was talking about. Sad that I can not use it.

Comment: If you would know how to use `grep`, `less` and more, you would not tell us, grep is not the best way to do that: `grep -P '/std\:\:cout\b[^"]*std\:\:endl/' -B5 -A5 | less`.

`grep` tells you which file the string was found and shows you 5 lines before and after the match. In `less` you could search again if needed, scroll through the code. And to detect the change in svn: use [`svn-bisect`](http://search.cpan.org/~infinoid/App-SVN-Bisect-1.1/bin/svn-bisect)

Comment: @Thomas Berger Sorry I am not that familiar with these ones. Also I meant karlphillip's comment. But I think the grep still suffers from the problem of too much information for me. The svn advice will be my next try...

Comment: You could try looking at the `callgrind` that comes with [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/); that might perhaps help you. Your problem is, though, that you have nothing distinctive to look for, and that remains a problem regardless of what you get to analyze the code. I'm surprised that you cannot tell by context which calls might be the diagnostics.  It suggests a somewhat chaotic approach to output in your main code.

Comment: FWIW, debugging code is better sent to standard error than standard output. In future, use a distinctive function or macro or even comment to track debug code. I don't indent temporary debug code, so if I ran into this problem, I'd be able `grep` for alphanumerics in column 1 of a file.  It doesn't take long to find anything that's astray. Permanent debug code looks like regular code, but uses special functions or macros, so it is also distinctive. Also include distinctive text in with the diagnostic! After this experience, make sure you make life easy for yourself.

Comment: Now that you mention it I see it myself why do I only use callgrind for profiling. But you are right with the distinctiveness. Normally I use special debug functions but this one did not seem worthy for me. This was a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a `printf` - do a macro that will call `printf` adding to it the file name and line number (these are `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`). Just name the macro `printf` and call `::printf` for the original function.

If it's `cout` - a bit trickier, but you can try to put breakpoint there and see where it's called from, you'll find it in the end.

For the next time - always use dedicated debug printing functions or wrapper macros that could be easily separated from the rest of the code by a single compiler switch.

Comment: Ok I will give this one a shot and hope its a printf ;)

Comment: @Nobody - make sure you include this macro in all your code base, I hope you have one single .H file included everywhere for that:-)

Comment: Thats my problem for now. But I am through with most so chances are that it's a std::cout.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need no fancy version control system! All you need is the self-discipline to mark all (yes, *all*) debugging output with a /* REMOVE ME */ comment.

It only took me 30 years to learn this.

Comment: +1: It is always the problem with programmers that they hate doing the extra work.

Comment: To help with discipline: `#define REMOVE_ME`, so you can write `REMOVE_ME printf("%d",x);`. If it's not a comment, you can change it to somethign the compiler will reject.

Answer (score 1):

This page: http://sclogger.sourceforge.net/
has a program enabling you to log syscalls. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

In the future, you can do something like the following.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
std::cout << "Debugging message" << std::endl;
#endif
```

You can control whether the symbol DEBUG is defined at compilation time.

Comment: The web page includes the information "The module works only on 2.4.x Linux kernels".  That's of limited value these days.

Answer (score 1):

You wanted a better way:

Use version control!  Then diff your working copy against your base revision; assuming you haven't made zillions of changes, it should be easy to find your `printf`.

**UPDATE**

If you don't know what revision you added this behaviour, then simply do a binary search.  Run your app at revision 1000 (for example), then 500, then 750, then 625, etc. etc.  It's really the same approach as locating the point in time where a bug was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in linux, you could use `grep` to parse the whole codetree at ones and let you show every hit for "std::cout". If you let print only one value, you should see the relevant line really fast.

Or you may look for a regular expression, if you know that there was no " in your debug line: `s/std\:\:cout\b[^"]*std\:\:endl/`.

To detect the change in svn: use [`svn-bisect`](http://search.cpan.org/~infinoid/App-SVN-Bisect-1.1/bin/svn-bisect)

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, I always have something like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
int dbg_printf(char * format, ...) {

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);

    vsnprintf(my_printf_buf, my_printf_bufsize, format, ap);
    uart3_putstr(my_printf_buf); // debug connector

    va_end(ap);

    return 0;
}
#else
#define dbg_printf(format, ...)
#endif
```

Good thing is that when you are not debugging, all those dbg_printf() you have on your code are eaten by the pre-processor and don't bloat your code.